# Python: How to make integers from a stream of character data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, char, integer, type-conversion

In my project, I have a special processor which is sending out 12 bytes and on my PC I have a python script which is reading those 12 bytes into a `list`. I'm pasting one such packet I have received into my list below:

```
packet1 = [255, 253, 99, 0, 19, 207, 0, 31, 25, 255, 249, 21]
```

I must combine every three elements(bytes), to make a meaningful value. So, that when I combine all of them successfully I should have 4 integers.

For example when I combine the first three values of the list `255, 253, 99` I should get `-699`. **That's right I need it as a signed integer.**

The way I was doing this in my C program was, like this:

```
uint8_t x = 255;
uint8_t y = 253;
uint8_t z = 99;

int convert(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t z)
{
    int result = (x << 24) + (y << 16) + (z << 8);
    result = result >> 8;
    return result;
}
```

By left shifting `x`, `y` and `z` by `8` and pushing all of them back right by `8`, and catching the result into an integer data format variable, **I was making sure that I getting a signed value.**

***How to achieve this effect in Python?***

Help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = struct.pack('BBBB', 255, 253, 99, 0)
>>> b = struct.unpack('>i', a)
>>> b[0] / 256
-669
```

you can use little endian.

```
>>> a = struct.pack('<BBBB',  0, 99, 253, 255)
>>> b = struct.unpack('<i', a)
>>> b[0] / 256
-669
```

Comment: Thank you Yejing. I need to understand this struct package.